# Query taking too much time to load data

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, inner-join

I am selecting data from a set of tables with join, but when I execute this it is taking too much time. `applicationusagelog` table has bulk data.

```
   SELECT  CONVERT(varchar(6),( AccessTime/3600))
            + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), (AccessTime % 3600) / 60), 2)
            + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), AccessTime % 60), 2) as AccessTime
            From
            (
                Select SUM(DATEPART(SECOND,LogTime)) as AccessTime
                From   applicationusagelog
                       Inner Join usermaster    On usermaster.EmployeeID=applicationusagelog.CreatedBy
                       Inner Join em_masteruser On em_masteruser.id=usermaster.OrganizationId
                Where  Cast(applicationusagelog.CreatedOn as date) Between '01-01-2018' And '04-04-2018' 
                And    em_masteruser.id='1' 
                And    applicationusagelog.ApplicationName not in
                        (
                            SELECT  master_domainapp.domainname 
                            From    master_domainapp
                                    Inner Join master_category_application On master_category_application.CategoryId=master_domainapp.CategoryId
                                    Inner Join em_masteruser On em_masteruser.id=master_domainapp.CreatedBy
                            Where  em_masteruser.id='1' 
                            And    master_category_application.CreatedBy='1'
                        )
            )x
```

someone help to reduce the loading time...

Comment: fix code indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the `NOT IN` condition with a `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT master_domainapp.domainname
INTO #domainnames
FROM master_domainapp
INNER JOIN master_category_application ON master_category_application.CategoryId = master_domainapp.CategoryId
INNER JOIN em_masteruser ON em_masteruser.id = master_domainapp.CreatedBy
WHERE em_masteruser.id = '1'
    AND master_category_application.CreatedBy = '1'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), (AccessTime / 3600)) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), (AccessTime % 3600) / 60), 2) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), AccessTime % 60), 2) AS AccessTime
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(DATEPART(SECOND, LogTime)) AS AccessTime
    FROM applicationusagelog
    INNER JOIN usermaster ON usermaster.EmployeeID = applicationusagelog.CreatedBy
    INNER JOIN em_masteruser ON em_masteruser.id = usermaster.OrganizationId
    LEFT JOIN #domainnames ON #domainnames.domainname = applicationusagelog.ApplicationName
    WHERE Cast(applicationusagelog.CreatedOn AS DATE) BETWEEN '01-01-2018'
            AND '04-04-2018'
        AND em_masteruser.id = '1'
        AND #domainnames.domainname IS NULL
    ) x
```

This may improve performance if the tables in the `NOT IN` sub query are heavy.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the casting of createdon to datetime in the where clause is the main culprit. After using the cast, the database cannot use an index anymore to reduce to potential resulset set to your date range. This in turn forces the database to look at the entire range of dates, which in turn results in a lot of very slow disk access.

You should change the field type of createdon to a date format (like datetime)  and write the query without casting. If it's still slow after that, place an index on the createdon field.